# how to retrieve the parameters that are passed in the url of a asp file

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am passing two variable in the URL to a classic asp page like this -

```
www.webart.com/classic.asp?a=1&b=18
```

now in classic.asp file i have to call a function that need these two variable like this

```
function getValues(a,b)
{
    content.....;
}
```

and i am not able to get the value of a and b in asp page.

Comment: You need to post more code or something: which line of your getValues function gives an "object expected" error? How are you calling the function? Note that a function can only "have" (aka return) a single value. And why are you complicating this with a function, anyway?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if JavaScript inside the same page you could try

```
function getValues(<%=Request.QueryString("a")%>,<%=Request.QueryString("b")%>)
```

Full code sample:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function dotest (a, b)
{
    alert (a);
    alert (b);
};
</script>
</head>
<body onload="dotest (<%=Request.QueryString("a")%>,<%=Request.QueryString("b")%>);">
test
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am geting syntax error in getvalues function if i am doing this

Comment: what type of parameters? integer, or string?

Comment: also, this is how CALL function, not how DECLARE

Comment: see this getValue func is defiend in a js file which is already added with this asp page . and it is taking 2 variable 1 int and another str

Comment: but this <%=Request.QueryString("a")%> is working just for integer . not for string

Comment: use quota for string: onload="dotest ("<%=Request.QueryString("a")%>","<%=Request.QueryString("b")%>");"

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your requirement but you can fetch the value on page with very basic syntax:

```
<%=Request.QueryString("a")%>
<%=Request.QueryString("b")%>
```

Comment: here in getvalues i am geting this error :
Object Expected

Comment: @user21 That syntax is shorthand for `Call Response.Write(Request.QueryString("a"))` PM is trying to explain that if you just want to display the values you don't need [tag:javascript] you can just use the `<%= %>` or `<% Call Response.Write() %>` to write your values direct to the HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at it that might help you understand:
In your called page, in the part that processes on the server:

```
<%
'this is server-side code
a = request.querystring("a")
b = request.querystring("b")
%>
<!-- now this is mostly client side code below -->
<!-- with some parts assembled server-side -->
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
a is equal to <%=a%><br>
b is equal to <%=b%><br>
</body>
</html>
```